# Synchronizing non-DB SQL Server objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are a number of tools available for synchronizing Tables, Indexes, Views, Stored Procedures and objects within a database. (We love RedGate here, and throw a lot of money their way).

However, I'm having a very difficult time finding tools that will help with Jobs, Logins and Linked Servers.

Do these things exist? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

for logins check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992.  basically a couple of microsoft created stored procedures that will output scripts that can be run on any server to reproduce the logins and their passwords.

not sure on the other 2 things though